# Tsung error: can't start newbeam on host

Tags: erlang, tsung

I have been trying to get tsung to connect to a box I have running kubuntu 12.04

Here is the client portion of my config

```
<clients>
    <client host="klaptop" weight="1" maxusers="500"/>
</clients>
```

I run tsung with the following command

```
tsung -f /var/tsung/xml/config.xml -l /var/tsung/logs/ start
```

I get the following error in my tsung_controller log file

```
=INFO REPORT==== 20-Jun-2012::15:06:01 ===
ts_config_server:(0:<0.72.0>) Can't start newbeam on host klaptop (reason: timeout) !     Aborting!
```

I have read the manual's trouble shooting and tried to make sure that all of my bases are covered
(same erlang version, ssh connection works without password, hostnames are set up right, etc)

I have confirmed connectivity with the example they gave, here are my results.

```
[/var/tsung]$ erl -rsh ssh -sname foo -setcookie mycookie
Erlang R15B01 (erts-5.9.1) [source] [64-bit] [smp:8:8] [async-threads:0] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

Eshell V5.9.1  (abort with ^G)
(foo@macbook)1> slave:start(klaptop,bar,"-setcookie mycookie").
{ok,bar@klaptop}
```

The user manual seems to make the assumption that once the connection works in erlang, tsung will also work, this is not the case for me though, I am still getting the same timeout issue.

I am not sure how to further debug this, any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

UPDATE:
As requested in the comments I tried using the IP.  With the following config

```
<client host="klaptop" weight="1" maxusers="500">
  <ip value="10.160.1.89"></ip>
</client>
```

I got the same error though.

Comment: There's always a chance that the issue is somehow related with name resolution. Can you try the above steps using direct IPs of nodes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had similar problem, it's possible that ssh key checking might get in the way.
Try this:

1. Use tsung 1.4.3 or newer
2. Create a script file (say, some_dir/ssh_no_check):

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   /usr/bin/ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $@
   ```
3. Make it executable.
4. Add:

   ```
    -r some_dir/ssh_no_check
   ```

to your tsung command params.

This will disable ssh key checking for tsung.

Comment: Yes!  This fixed the problem.  Thank you so much.  Out of curiosity, are you running on a mac?

Comment: @copacetic Glad it helped! No, most of the time I'm running tsung on Linux.

Answer (score 2):

```
Can't start newbeam on host XXXX (reason: timeout)
```

In my case (Debian 6.0, tsung 1.4.2) the reason of this error was that client also must has ssh key to connect to master. There is no explicit mention about it in documentation.

Answer (score 0):

1. Ensure ssh key verification is disabled

~/.ssh/config
Host *
      StrictHostKeyChecking no
      UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null

2. **Make sure all ports are accessible across controller and worker nodes.**
   *If it is in the cloud make sure firewall or security groups allow all ports.*

3.Erlang, Tsung must have same version.

4.Ensure all machines are reachable to each other

5.Run erlang test

erl -rsh ssh -name subbu -setcookie tsung
Erlang R16B03-1 (erts-5.10.4) [source] [64-bit] [smp:2:2] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

Eshell V5.10.4  (abort with ^G)
(daya@ip-10-0-100-224.ec2.internal)1> slave:start("worker1.com",bar,"-setcookie tsung").

Warning: Permanently added 'worker1,10.0.100.225' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
{ok,bar@worker1}

Run this test from controller to all worker nodes.

You should be able run tests without any issues.

Good Luck!

Subbu