# Tsung: Can't start newbeam (reason: no_rsh)

Tags: erlang, tsung

I try to start tsung slaves on EC2 machines.
Keys are in place and the test with

```
erl -rsh ssh -sname root -setcookie mycookie
slave:start('i-d6807c9d',root,"-setcookie mycookie").
> {ok,'root@i-d6807c9d'}
```

is working.

When I now execute tsung I get the following error message: no_rsh.
The Erlang documentation writes that no_rsh means "There is no rsh program on the computer.".

```
78 =INFO REPORT==== 18-Sep-2012::10:51:15 ===
79     ts_config_server:(5:<0.52.0>) SYSINFO:Current path: /usr/lib/erlang/lib/tsung-1.4.2/ebin/tsung.beam
80 
81 =INFO REPORT==== 18-Sep-2012::10:51:15 ===
82        ts_job_notify:(5:<0.64.0>) No listen port defined, can't open listening socket·
83 
84 =INFO REPORT==== 18-Sep-2012::10:51:15 ===
85            ts_os_mon:(5:<0.49.0>) os_mon disabled
86 =INFO REPORT==== 18-Sep-2012::10:51:15 ===
87               ts_mon:(5:<0.53.0>) Activate clients with text backend
88 
89 =INFO REPORT==== 18-Sep-2012::10:51:15 ===
90     ts_config_server:(0:<0.73.0>) Can't start newbeam on host 'i-d6807c9d' (reason: no_rsh) ! Aborting!
```

Does anyone know how to get this running?

thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the mistake. 
I used the tsung parameter "-r" to set remote connector to a debug script mentioned here: [Tsung error: can't start newbeam on host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11129080/tsung-error-cant-start-newbeam-on-host).

This script was not available on the EC2 instance. Running the test without the "-r" option worked.